# Google plus API shutdown, How it will affect Google auth2 login for web sites?

Tags: google-plus, google-signin, google-api-client, google-auth-library

I am confused with shutdown notification mails from Google one of the recent mail mentioned as

> ***projects directly requesting the “plus.me” scope are affected***. This scope may have been listed in some emails, even if not directly
>   requested by your project. We apologize for any confusion caused.

I am using following JS code for login, may I know will it affect anyway due to Google plus api shutdown?

```
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload="this.onload=function(){};HandleGoogleApiLibrary()" onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//google login starts
function HandleGoogleApiLibrary() {
    // Load "client" & "auth2" libraries
    gapi.load('client:auth2', {
        callback: function() {
            // Initialize client library
            // clientId & scope is provided => automatically initializes auth2 library
            gapi.client.init({
                apiKey: 'API KEY HERE',
                clientId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'                        
            }).then(
                // On success
                function(success) {
                    // After library is successfully loaded then enable the login button
                    //CODE AFTER SUCCESS
                }, 
                // On error
                function(error) {                    
                    alert('Error : Failed to Load Library');
                }
            );
        },
        onerror: function() {
            // Failed to load libraries
        }
    });
}

// Click on login button
$("#login-button").on('click', function() {
    // API call for Google login
    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn().then(
        // On success
        function(success) {
            // API call to get user information
            gapi.client.request({ path: 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me' }).then(
                // On success
                function(success) {
                    console.log(success);
                    var user_info = JSON.parse(success.body);                       
                    //VALIDATION                 
                },
                // On error
                function(error) {                                               
                    alert('Error : Failed to login');
                }
            );
        },
        // On error
        function(error) {
            $("#login-button").removeAttr('disabled');
            alert('Error : Login Failed');
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is good news and bad news.

The good news is that you're not using any of the plus *scopes*.

The bad news is that you're using the plus API, which is also being shut down, and which was mentioned in a previous email that should have been sent to you.

Specifically, this chunk of code:

```
gapi.client.request({ path: 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me' }).then(
```

calls the "plus.people.me" API.

Fortunately, you should be able to switch to a different API, such as the ["userinfo" API](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/oauth2/v2/oauth2.userinfo.get), by changing endpoints to

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo
```

You may also wish to look into the more modern [People API](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get), which works very similarly, and is slightly more complicated, but can provide other profile fields.

Comment: I changed endpoint to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?alt=json 
Output looks like
{
email: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx@xxxx.xxx"
​email_verified: true
​family_name: "xx"
​gender: "male"
​given_name: "xxxxxxxxx"
​locale: "en"
​name: "xxxxx xxxxxxx"
​picture: "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/photo.jpg"
​profile: "https://plus.google.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
​sub: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
Here Key "sub" is unique Google Id, in previous version it was "Id"

Comment: Hey, I used same one in my rails application [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55043208/10522579), using [reference](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#discovery)